# ffmpeg: scale output cropped width/height doesn't work

Tags: ffmpeg, scale, crop

I'm trying to crop video frames with ffmpeg, and I would like to scale the cropped image automatically.
I saw an option at av filter: http://ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html#SEC41

./ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "crop=640:480,**scale=ow:oh**" -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234

I receive an error: *Error when evaluating the expression 'oh'*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
./ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "scale=640:ih*640/iw, crop=640:480" -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Above code will first scale the video to `640` and maintain the aspect ratio height,
then crop to `640x480.`

Comment: How does the crop choose what parts to crop? Is it guaranteed to always take the exact center `640x480` of the video?

Comment: @user779159 Yes, it crops the exact center.
"It defaults to `(in_w-out_w)/2`" as detailed [here](http://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're getting:

```
Error when evaluating the expression 'oh'.
Maybe the expression for out_w:'ow' or for out_h:'oh' is self-referencing.
```

Because you try to set the output w/h to the output w/h?! What you want to do is

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "crop=640:480,scale=iw:ih" -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

That is, setting the output w/h to what the input width (iw) and input height (ih) was.

Note that you will get an error if the source video is smaller than what you try to crop to (640:480). You may use ffmpeg's expression syntax to first check if a crop/scale is necessary to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to replace `ow` and `oh` with numbers, representing the width and height to scale the video to, respectively.

Comment: I need to change the crop window dynamically (I've made a few change on ffmpeg) and I would like to scale it according to the actual cropped window. As I understand the values 'ow' and 'oh' should do the job, doesn't it?

Comment: Nope. You must put numbers where the docs say `ow` and `oh`.

Comment: Instead of ow and oh (which are not constants) you can use expressions that ARE constants like out_w and out_h.

Comment: ow/oh are aliases for out_w/out_h. Those are constants that are set by ffmpeg and should not be exchanged for numbers (that would loose the whole point of having them).